# knockoutjs mapping plugin removing functions from objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I currently have the following objects that I am using to map some JSON data to:

```
function Regions() {
    var self = this;

    self.regions = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addRegion = function () {
        // add a region
    };

    self.removeRegion = function (region) {
        // remove a region
    };
}

function Region() {
    var self = this;

    self.region = ko.observable("");

    self.products = new Products();
}

function Products() {
    var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addProduct = function () {
        // add a product
    };

    self.removeProduct = function (product) {
        // remove a product
    };
}

function Product() {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable("");
    self.price = ko.observable("");
}
```

I am attempting to map the JSON response from the server by doing:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(appViewModel, {}, new Regions());
```

This is working fine except for that the functions on the Products object are being overwritten by the mapping plugin whereas the functions on the Regions object are still there.

Is there a way of doing this so that I can keep my functions on the Products object?

Comment: Please update your question and add enough code so we can actually *reproduce* the issue - preferably in a runnable Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping plug works okay for the first level because it uses the `new Regions()` as the instance. It doesn't know what instance/function instantiate for the internal regions array.

It creates entries that have the same name but are *not* instances of the Product() function - mapping doesn't know about it so the objects are just a collection of observable properties. Does that make sense?

Have a look at the section *Customizing object construction using “create”* in the mapping documentation. You'd need to tell the pluging how to construct the child objects in this way.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll look into that and see how I get on. Thanks